# Palindrome program, cannot terminate loop, Project Euler #4

Tags: java, loops, recursion

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Euler4{
    public static void main(String [] args){
                int size = 0;
        int product = 0;

        for(int i = 102; i > 100; i--){
            for(int j = 102; j > 100; j--){
                ArrayList<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                product = i*j;
                int index = 0;
                while(product > 0){
                    digits.add(index,product%10);
                    product /= 10;
                    index++;
                }
                for(int element : digits)
                    System.out.println("digits :" + element);   
                size = digits.size() - 1;

                if(test(0,size,digits)){
                    System.out.println("i and j " + i + " " + j);
                    break;  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean test(int i, int size, ArrayList<Integer> digits){

        if(digits.get(size).equals(digits.get(i))){

            if(size == i || size - i == 1){
                return true;

            }else{
                System.out.println("i: " + i + " size: " + size + " digits@i: " + digits.get(i) +" digits@size " + digits.get(i));
                size--;
                i++;

                if(!test(i, size, digits))  
                    return false;
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
digits :4 index: 0
digits :0 index: 1
digits :4 index: 2
digits :0 index: 3
digits :1 index: 4
digits :2 index: 0
digits :0 index: 1
digits :3 index: 2
digits :0 index: 3
digits :1 index: 4
digits :2 index: 0
digits :0 index: 1
digits :3 index: 2
digits :0 index: 3
digits :1 index: 4
digits :1 index: 0
digits :0 index: 1
digits :2 index: 2
digits :0 index: 3
digits :1 index: 4
i: 0 size: 4 digits@i: 1 digits@size 1
i: 1 size: 3 digits@i: 0 digits@size 0
```

I think there's a problem with the while loop and a problem with the recursion. The values that get ran through the test() method is the last set of values that goes into the array and that is 10201 so then even though the while loop messed up, the recursive method should still have returned true. I don't know why it's not.

This is the problem: 
http://projecteuler.net/problem=4

Thanks.

EDIT: I fixed it up to be a bit more efficient and to give the max palindrome instead of just listing palindromes. Here's the final if anyone is interested: http://pastebin.com/qJUpZVzK

Comment: Is this Project Euler, Problem Number 4? If so, you should say so in the question. If not, you should probably avoid calling your class `Euler4`, it will lead to the wrong assumption.

Comment: Right, I'll go change that.

Comment: consider using a stack to detect palindrome, if the string == the stack then its a palindrome.

Comment: Your issue with digits is using remainder of division by ten that gives funky results. For instance 1002 % 10 = 2, 1001 % 10 = 1, 1000 % 10 = 0. Use a logarithm or cast number to `String` and store its length. See [this ideone clip](http://ideone.com/EtLiDN) for instance.

Comment: @t0mppa: right, but isn't that what i want? I get the last digit with the modulus, then get rid of the last digit with the division. The issue seems to lie in the while loop condition.

Comment: Sorry, mistaken what you wanted with the printout. It said "digits", which to me was referring to number of digits left at that point in loop, to debug how many iterations it takes, instead of saying "digit" and referring to a singular one. Loop condition was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third call to `test` is returning `true`, but your second call to `test` is not using that value.  It's falling to the bottom of the method and returning `false`, when you actually want it to return `true`.

When you call `test` recursively, you want to return `true` (from `test`) if the recursive call returned `true`.

Change

```
if(!test(i, size, digits))  
      return false;
```

near the bottom, to

```
return test(i, size, digits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will never reach 0, because the condition will always be satisfied.

```
            while(product > 0){
                digits.add(index,product%10);
                product /= 10;
                index++;
            }
```

To be honest, I think the easiest way to check for palindromes is this:

```
public boolean palindrome (int n) {
    return String.valueOf(n).equals(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(n)).reverse().toString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies here:

```
while(product > 0){
    digits.add(index,product%10);
    product /= 10;
    index++;
}
```

`product` can never be reduced to a negative number, (less than 0), by dividing by 10; which means that you will never exit this while loop. Lets look at this further:

```
1- product is created and it's value is 102*102=10404. (The first time through the for loops.)
2- product is divided by 10 to get 1040.4
3- While loop is checked, 1040.4 > 0, enter again.
4- product is divided by 10 to get 104.04
5- While loop is checked, 104.04 > 0, enter again.
```

Repeat steps 4 and 5 infinitely, because even if you keep dividing below 1, it will always be above 0. (Eg. 0.0000000000000010404 > 0)

Comment: But when integers divide, they ignore the decimal. Also, wouldn't the array index continue infintely? In this case, the array goes to an index of 4, and then repeats from index 0.

Comment: Humph...got me. Carry on. :P